# Changing Image Src after animation in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

So I am making a polaroid slideshow effect and I want to change the image after the animation in Jquery. I tried adding Delays but maybe I'm not doing it right?

Here's my code and maybe you can help find a way to add transitional images

**Jquery**

```
$(function () { // DOCUMENT ready shorthand
    function polariodSlideshow() {
        $("#polaroid").animate({ opacity: 1, top: 80 }, 1500);
        $("#polaroid").animate({ opacity: 0, top: 250 }, 1800);
        $("#polaroid").animate({ opacity: 0, top: 0 }, 1900, polariodSlideshow);
    }
    polariodSlideshow();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="polaroid" style="position:absolute ;width: 100%; height: -3000px; margin-top: 35px; opacity:0.0"> 
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <br /> <br />
<div  style="background-color: #EEEEEE; height:145%; width:40%; box-shadow: 0px 10px 5px #888888; display:inline-block; margin-left: 15%;">

<div id="slideshow">
<img id="centerIMG" src="images/cityscape.jpg"  style=" margin-top:15px; width: 94%; margin-left:3%;" />

</div>

<div style=""> <br /> <br /> </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I'm looking to add the switch after the third animation, so the callback function would happen after the image is changed when the animation is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just use the completion handler from the third animation:

```
$(function () { // DOCUMENT ready shorthand
    var imgs = ["src1.jpg", "src2.jpg", "src3.jpg", "src4.jpg"];
    var cntr = 0;
    function polariodSlideshow() {
        $("#polaroid").animate({ opacity: 1, top: 80 }, 1500);
        $("#polaroid").animate({ opacity: 0, top: 250 }, 1800);
        $("#polaroid").animate({ opacity: 0, top: 0 }, 1900, function() {
            // change the image here
            var newImg = imgs[cntr % imgs.length];
            ++cntr;
            // use newImg here

            // then kick off the next iteration
            polariodSlideshow();
        });
    }
    polariodSlideshow();
});
```

If the new image .src is not already cached, then you may also need to add code that waits for it to load or better yet, make sure it's precached so that isn't an issue.

Comment: It worked!
How would I do it if I wanted to change more than one image?@jfriend00

Comment: @コードバリノ - I don't understand your new question.  If you want to change multiple images in that spot in the code, why can't you just change multiple images there?

Comment: Sorry I fairly new to Jquery so I was wondering if it loops again won't the src keep changing towards the same image?
I was wondering if there was a way to change the SRC to different images each time it looped back from the callback @jfriend00

Comment: @コードバリノ - you can declare a counter outside of `polariodSlideshow()` that you increment each time through and that enables you to pick a different image each time.  You could put all the image URLs into an array and use the counter to index into the array.

Comment: honestly confused as hell with the indexing to array part. I will do some googling to try to figure it out cause i don't want to annoy you in asking to many questions. @jfriend00

Comment: @コードバリノ - Since it looks like you might be new here at StackOverflow, are you aware that when someone answers your question, you can click on the green checkmark to the left of that answer to mark it as the best answer.  This rewards the answerer and earns you some reputation points for follow the proper procedure here.

Comment: I used the new code but the image doesn't swap in, was I suppose to put something where you commented use newImg?

@jfriend00

Comment: @コードバリノ - yes, you have to add the code to actually change the image there, just like you have to fill in the image URLs into the array that you have.  I don't know what your HTML looks like or what DOM element you're trying to change so I can't be more specific about how to actually change the image.

Comment: The HTML I posted above is all I really have on the page aside from the <HTML> , <Body> , etc.

I changed the src names you gave me to actual image files I have in a folder so I just wanted to know what the code was to actually create that image swap from the original to the new one.@jfriend00

Comment: @コードバリノ - If it's the `centerIMG` image you're trying to change, then you would use `$("#centerIMG").attr("src", newImg);`

Comment: Thank you that worked, I am looking over the code and I am trying to comprehend how it works so what I see is.

1. It animates
2. [Don't understand how counter works]
3. New image has been loaded
4. Places new image in the center img spot
5. Reruns the whole function

Can you explain how the 
    var newImg = imgs[cntr % imgs.length]; 
works?

I just want to understand it so I don't have to comeback and ask the same question again.

Comment: See the Remainder `%` operator described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder).  If you take the remainder from an increasing counter divided by the length of the array, you will always get an index in the array that steadily increases and then starts back at the beginning of the array again - repeating the cycle over and over.  It's a trick for cycling through a specific range.

Comment: So basically, it starts like this.
1. 0 out of 4 | 2. 1 out of 4 | 3. 2 out of 4.... and so on right?
the ++cntr is steadily increasing the number right? So what happens when the percent is equal to max like 4 out of 4? How does it know to got back to 0? or 1? @jfriend00

Comment: @コードバリノ - please read the link I gave you in my previous comment about the `%` operator.